# declaring that a value belongs to some range in matlab

Tags: matlab, vector, range, declaration

I have a task to calculate some f(x) function in which x belongs to [-4,4] range and h=0.5.

At first I tried to write x=rand*(4-(-4))+(-4)) but then I guessed that I was doing wrong and I needed a vector, so I wrote this: A=-4:0.5:4; I got A vector with [-4,4] range and h=0.5 but I don't know how to write that x∈A

Any ideas?

**Edit:**
Sorry if my question confused you. I'm not a native speaker and sometimes I find it hard to translate what I'm trying to do.

To clarify, I was given a function

[image]

x∈[-4, 4] and h=0.5

I did this:

```
A=-4:0.5:4;

//Here I want to write that x is from A range (x∈A) and I don't know how.

if x>2
    disp (x^2+7);
elseif x>-3 && x<2
    disp (3*sin(x)+e^x);
elseif x<=-3
    disp ((x^2)/(3*cos(x)-2));
end;
```

Comment: Declaring that a value belongs to some range doesn't mean anything to me. Do you mean you want to generate a vector so that its values are in a specific range, or do you want to check if a vector's values are all in a specific range?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Could you edit your question to clarify what you mean?

Comment: I think (correct me if I'm wrong) what he's asking is: He has a range `A`, and a stepwise function `f(x)`. Now, he wants to generate a vector, `x` (which either contains several values, or 1 value...?) which contains values within the range, `A`. Is that correct?

Comment: Separate issue - What is the point of `h`? (You declare, `h=0.5`, but then don't use it in the script?) Does it define the distribution of `x`?

Comment: @David_G x isn't a vector. it's just a single value from A range.
I don't know what `h` is called but it does this kind of thing:
If I had a range `[-1,1]` and `h=0.5`, A would contain values `-1 -0.5 0 0.5 1`

Comment: `h` is used here `A=-4: 0.5 :4;`

Comment: Are -4 & 4 included in your vector? "-4" is the minimum value of "A" and "4" is the maximum value of "A". you could say that:      `if(min(A)<=x<=max(A))`(if -4 & 4 are included) or               `if(min(A)<x<max(A))`(if -4 & 4 aren't included)....

Comment: I think what you're asking for is a loop,a `for loop` to be precise,you should say `for x=min(A):h:max(A)  Computation end`          P.S: `e^x` is implemented as `exp(x)`

Comment: How do you want to pick `x` from `A`? Do you want to randomly pick it? Or do you want to incrementally pick it? (See @AaymanKhalid above for incrementally picking `x` from `A`!)

Comment: Your function is undefined at `x == 2`. Is this intentional?

Comment: @AaymanKhalid You are right. I needed exactly what you wrote. Thanks.

@David_G I needed random `x`. 
@wakjah I don't know. maybe it should be `x>=2` or `x>-3 && x<=2`. It doesn't really matter.

Thanks for your responses.

Answer (score 1):

use vectorization

```
h = 0.5;
x = linspace(-4, 4, h ); % equally spaced x
fx = ( x > 2 ).*( x.^2 + 7 ) + ...
     ( x <= 2 & x > -3 ) .* ( 3 *sin(x) + exp(x) ) + ...
     ( x <= -3 ) .* ( ( x.^2 ) ./ ( 3 * cos(x) -2 ) );
figure;
plot( x, fx ); title( 'f(x)' );
```

Comment: Thanks but I think your code is too complicated for me. I'm beginner and I can't understand more than half of its syntax. sorry.

Comment: What @user2379182 is doing is: Making `x`, so that it is a vector of values from -4 to 4, equally spaced by `h`. Then, `x`, which now spans the range `A`, with separation `h`, is fed into *f(x)*, which is defined by `fx`. By using logic (`x>2`,etc), you don't need an if-loop. Then, the result is plotted.